# How to install opencv python on M1 mac WITHOUT using an environment?

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, apple-m1

I've recently switched to an M1 Mac, and I need to be able to install opencv, and while there are many guides for installing it with an environment, I need to be able to use it without activating an environment each time. I've been following [this guide](https://sayak.dev/install-opencv-m1/) and trying to adapt the instructions to work without a conda environment, but I've been getting `make: *** [all] Error 2` in the `make` step. I have no experience with building my own libraries from source, so I may be making an error here, but how can I build this so that it installs without an environment?

Comment: The message `make: *** [all] Error 2` gives almost no information about the problem: almost any fail in `make` call ends with such message. You need to find out the message about the **actual error**. For finding such message it is better to do single-threaded build (without option `-j`). "I've been following this guide and trying to adapt the instructions to work without a conda environment" - So you have performed your own steps. For being able to help you we need to know the exact steps you have performed.

Comment: I'll send you what I can. [this](https://pastebin.com/G3pfWijj) is my cmake command. I tried both `arch -arm64 make -j8` and `arch -arm64 make` separately resulting in the make error. I cannot find the make log file, do you know where I might find it? The only steps I diverged from the guide were not activating an environment and installing numpy through pip, which I tested and which works.

Comment: "I cannot find the make log file, do you know where I might find it?" - The error message is not in a log file. It is in `make` output, somewhere above the line you show.

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/KE4JR61K) is my make output

Comment: The line `error: function does not return NSString` is where the **actual error** starts. It is quite easy to find it: this is the **first** error message. Add the error message to the question post, so it will contain that important information.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried just installing it with [pip](http://%20https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)?
`pip install opencv-python`

there should also be some compiled [installers](https://opencv.org/releases/) for mac.

Comment: This is what I tried originally but I'm getting this error:
`ImportError: 

dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:

 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture`